# To save sensitive information in the Android internal storage what security steps we have to care about?

Tags: android

I want to store encrypted auth information ( username, password ) to the internal device storage and when necessary I wanna decode that username and password. What's the best practice to avoid hacking that sensitive information which is stored in the internal storage ( share preference ). Is there a secure way to store them so that root user or hacker not able to decode that information?

Comment: If someone could get some passwords from a device it is likely that it is their device. Why caring about their own account? Hacking yourself or? Why hacking yourself if you know the password?

Answer (score 1):

Someone with root access will most likely always be able to decode information stored on their device. For best practices on how to avoid that, or at least make it diffcult, have a look at this Android Developer page:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore

But even they say in the first sentence

> ...to make it more difficult to extract from the device...